# GitHub Probot : ERROR probot: Bad Request

Tags: github, github-api, probot

I am developing an application for Probot. I have configured `.env`and already downloaded PEM file in the folder.

Here is the content of file `index.js`.

```
module.exports = (robot) => {
robot.on('issues.opened', async context => {  
    const params = context.issue({ body: 'Hello World!' })
    return context.github.issues.createComment(params)
})
}
```

But I am getting this error.

```
  ERROR probot: Bad Request
  Error: Bad Request
      at Request.callback (/media/ashutosh/ASHUTOSH ( PERSONAL )/Gsoc/probot/practice/ashutosh-probot/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:696:15)
      at IncomingMessage.parser (/media/ashutosh/ASHUTOSH ( PERSONAL )/Gsoc/probot/practice/ashutosh-probot/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:906:18)
      at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I had this error because I had a typo in my Webhook Secret on GitHub, which didn't match my `.env` file

Answer (score 1):

This error not because of Probot, but the error is on GitHub ends.

This error is possibly because you have entered wrong User authorization call back URL, while creating a new GitHub application. Updating this will fix the issue.

[image: Create new GitHub Application]